# Vue.js 2 Set all reactive properties from API call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a vue component with some properties eg.

```js
import { getAPI } from "@/axios-api";
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "edit-profile-form",
  data() {
    return {
      first_name: "",
      last_name: "",
...
```

I also have an API call that will get these properties, which have exactly the same name eg.

```
{
   "first_name": "Jon",
   "last_name": "Doe"
}
```

Is there a way I can update both properties simultaneously? instead of doing

```js
axios.get('/url/').then(res => {
  this.first_name = res.first_name;
  this.first_name = res.first_name;
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to copy those fields into your `data` is to use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
axios.get('/url/').then(res => {
  Object.assign(this.$data, res.data)
});
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-assign-data?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)